# AttributeError: Unknown property interpolations

Tags: python

I am supposed to be showing images of a Gray-Scott Model by discretizing coupled differential equations.

I started getting this error message whe I added the imshow portion:

```py
  File "C:\Users\Chad Thomas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 912, in _update_property
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)

AttributeError: Unknown property interpolations
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is.
The error is from the imshow code at the bottom but I included the rest incase that helps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#parameters
N=128
F=.042
k=.062
Du=(2**-5)*(N**2/6.25)
Dv=adjust(1**-5)*(N**2/6.25)
tend=100                                      
dt=tend/N
t=0

#start arrays
U=np.ones((N,N))
V=np.zeros((N,N))

#Initial Value Boxes (20x20 in middle)
low=int(((N/2)-10))
high=int(((N/2)+10))+1
U[low:high,low:high]=.5
V[low:high,low:high]=.25

#Random Noise
U+=.01*np.random.random((N,N))
V+=.01*np.random.random((N,N))

#Solve
pstep=100
for t in range(tend):
    Usave=U.copy()
    M=U
    B=V
    U=-Du*(np.roll(U,1)+np.roll(U,-1)+np.roll(U,1,axis=False)+np.roll(U,-1,axis=False)-4*M)+(M*B*B)-F*(1-M)+(M+dt)
    Vsave=V.copy()
    V=-Dv*(np.roll(V,1)+np.roll(V,-1)+np.roll(V,1,axis=False)+np.roll(V,-1,axis=False)-4*B)-(M*B*B)+(F+k)*B+(B+dt)
    if t%pstep ==0:
        plt.imshow(U, interpolations='bicubic',cmap=plt.cm.jet)
        #plt.savefig("C:\Users\Chad Thomas\Desktop\Python Programs\plots\imshow-"+str(t//pstep).zfill(3)+".png")
```

I just want it to show an image of some sort at this point. (hopefully a square in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. `plt.imshow` accepts a keyword argument `interpolation` not `interpolations` (notice the missing `s` at the end).

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly as indicated: there is no property interpolations. But there is a property `interpolation`, so you will have more success if you change that line to

```py
plt.imshow(U, interpolation='bicubic',cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```